# How does failing to square a value in this version libcrypt++ cause a timing attack vulnerability?

Tags: timing-attack

I'm a crypto beginner and reading about blinding, and my fundamental understanding about preventing timing attacks is that you need to sort of process information in a way that will produce similar processing times for each set of operations.

In [CVE-2015-2141](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2015-2141) something as simple as [failure to call `r = modn.Square(r);`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/9425e16437439e68c7d96abef922167d68fafaff?diff=unified) in a single func seems to have caused a timing attack vulnerability in libcrypt++ in 2015.

[image]

I have a multi part question about this:

- First it seems like you'd need some special helper func designed to produce random timing results called in each subroutine to blind a func, why is the process of squaring a value sufficient?
- Second, surely this algorithm has many hundreds of routines that get called every single time it's used - it seems like if nearly all of the subroutines are blinded, the failure to blind just one wouldn't leak enough timing information to cause the entire function to be vulnerable to a timing attack, can someone explain this?
- Is the goal to make every subroutine take exactly the same amount of time to complete, or a random unpredictable time? Why couldn't we paste a helper function call into every module that runs in a securely random amount of time so the timing information released becomes useless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In CVE-2015-2141 something as simple as failure to call `r =
>   modn.Square(r);` in a single func seems to have caused a timing attack
>   vulnerability in libcrypt++ in 2015.

Actually no. That's not what CVE-2015-2141 is about. [What it is actually about](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/368) is that the loop originally did not have the squaring and this would result in sometimes not having the blinding removed in a later step after the private key operation which would leak enough information in about 2 signatures on the same message to recover the private key.

> First it seems like you'd need some special helper func designed to
>   produce random timing results called in each subroutine to blind a
>   func, why is the process of squaring a value sufficient?

The blinding here is achieved by the fact that computing a signature in rabin-williams is "effectively equivalent" to computing a square root of the message. So it kinda works like this:

- Pick $r\gets_\$ \{1,...,n-1\}$, compute $r^2\bmod n$ and $r^{-1}\bmod n$
- Let $m$ be a message, compute $m'=r^2\cdot m$
- Now compute the signature on $s'=\sqrt {m'}\bmod n=\sqrt {r^2\cdot m}\bmod n=r\cdot\sqrt {m}\bmod n$
- Finally unblind the signature to recover the actual signature $s=r^{-1}\cdot s'\bmod n$

Now what this achieves is prevent an attacker from knowing on which value exactly the private key operation was applied, which should thwart quite a few timing attacks.

> Is the goal to make every subroutine take exactly the same amount of
>   time to complete, or a random unpredictable time?

The standard strategy to thwart timing attacks is to either

- ensure the timing doesn't actually depend on the private value in question or
- ensure the timing doesn't actually correlate to known inputs and / or the private key in a meaningful way.

Randomizing the input to the private key operation is part of the second strategy.

Comment: And yes, that comment in the loop which says "JPM" does mean me :p

Comment: That's crazy. I reference some important open source crypto code and someone referenced in the comments on that code answers my question about it on SE O_o

Comment: On that note when I first read that comment I looked up the wiki for Jacobi requirements and was 100% lost. This field is like rocket science, I have a long way to go.